# Why does Solve give different answers when specifying coefficients at different time?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

**Context**

I would like to find a specific - eventually complex - root of a 4th order polynomial as a function of a purely imaginary parameter $i\lambda$ who is continuous in $\lambda$. I am thus looking for a function $f$

$$f(\lambda)= \text{Solve}[x-(a+b x+c x^2+d x^3+e x^4)i\lambda]=0,x]$$

for different sets of $a, b, c, d, e$ real numbers.

**Attempt**

I know that the ordering of the different roots that come out of the Solve function in mathematica is so that in principle one solution might not be continuous in $\lambda$. However, I find that depending on the time in my code at which I define the values of $a, b, c, d, e$, the solutions that come out of Solve are different:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

f1[\[Lambda]_]=Solve[x-(a+b x+c x^2+d x^3+e x^4) \[Lambda]==0,x][[3,1,2]];

a = 2.6;
b = 4.5;
c = 6.0;
d = 5.9;
e = 3.2;

f2[\[Lambda]_]=Solve[x-(a+b x+c x^2+d x^3+e x^4) \[Lambda]==0,x][[2,1,2]];

\[Lambda]pts = I*Table[\[Lambda],{\[Lambda],0,5,0.002}];
nb\[Lambda]= \[Lambda]pts//Length;

xintermediate[1]:=x/.FindRoot[x-(a+b x+c x^2+d x^3+e x^4)\[Lambda]pts[[1]],{x,I*(10^(-5))^.5},MaxIterations->1000];
xintermediate[n_]:= xintermediate[n]= x/.FindRoot[x-(a+b x+c x^2+d x^3+e x^4)  \[Lambda]pts[[n]],{x,xintermediate[n-1]},MaxIterations->1000];
NumResult =Table[xintermediate[nn],{nn,1,nb\[Lambda]}];

ptsint1[\[Lambda]_]:=If[\[Lambda]==0,0,f1[\[Lambda]]]//N;
SolveResult1=Map[ptsint1[#]&, \[Lambda]pts];

ptsint2[ \[Lambda]_]:=If[\[Lambda]==0,0,f2[\[Lambda]]]//N;
SolveResult2=Map[ptsint2[#]&, \[Lambda]pts];

{Show[ListLinePlot[NumResult//Re,ImageSize->Large,PlotStyle->{Thickness[0.01],Gray,Dashed,Opacity[0.3]}],ListLinePlot[{SolveResult2//Re,SolveResult1//Re},ImageSize->Medium],PlotRange->All],Show[ListLinePlot[NumResult//Im,ImageSize->Large,PlotStyle->{Thickness[0.01],Black,Dashed,Opacity[0.3]},PlotRange->All],ListLinePlot[{SolveResult2//Im,SolveResult1//Im},ImageSize->Medium,PlotRange->All]]}
```

Here I have defined 2 different functions f1 (orange in the plot) and f2 (blue in the plot) that select specific roots out of the Solve function, f1 having to find the roots of a generic polynomial with $a,b,c,d,e$ undefined, and f2 having to find the roots of a specific polynomial with only $\lambda$ left free.

I also display the numerical result (dashed grey points) I obtain not using Solve but instead relying on a purely numerical method to find the roots of the polynomial in a continuous manner with $\lambda$ with the FindRoot function.

I display in the figure the results I get for f1, f2, and the numerical implementation for both the real and imaginary parts of the roots as a function of $\lambda$
[image]

As you can see the two different implementations of Solve do not get the same results (I selected the closest solutions to display as an example).

**Questions**

Why does it matter when I specify the values of the coefficients for Solve ? Especially since when I specify those values mathematica tells me "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result."

For my specific problem, I can see that specifying the coefficients yields the expected result I want, however, I would rather extract an analytical expression out of Solve that would thus depend on both $a,b,c,d,e$ and $\lambda$ that would be continuous in $\lambda$, is it possible ?

Thanks a lot for your comments and answers !

Comment: I believe the answer might be that the order of the roots varies with the parameters. See `ReImPlot[Evaluate@ SolveValues[x - (a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4) I* λ == 0 // Rationalize, x(*,Quartics->False*)], {λ, 0, 5}, ReImStyle -> {Dashing[{}], DotDashed}, PlotRange -> 1.5]`. The ordering is slightly different depending on whether you return roots in terms of `Power` ("principal n-th roots") or `Root` objects (using `Quartics -> False`), which are sorted by their real part.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed I agree that the ordering in Solve varies with the parameter $\lambda$. However, I still do not understand why is it that Solve gives different answers whether I specify the values of {a,b,c,d,e} before or after the Solve command, which seems to tell me that it first solves an analytical problem before numericizing it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but there seem to be two things that affect what is observed: `Solve` puts the solutions in some order. The order of the parametric solutions does not have to be the same as the order of the solution after the parameters have been given specific values. (Compare `{SolveValues[-2 x^2 + x + 3 == 0, x], SolveValues[c x^2 + b x + a == 0, x] /. {a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> -2}}` or
`{SolveValues[-2 x^2 + x + a == 0, x], SolveValues[c x^2 + b x + a == 0, x] /. {b -> 1, c -> -2}}`.) The other is that principal roots have discontinuities and might not track your `FindRoot` solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry if I am not clear enough. I agree with the two points you raise. My questions are rather,
1) why is it that the order is not the same whether you specify the parameters before or after using Solve ?
2) The parametrisation of the solutions are even different whether you specify the parameters before or after using Solve ?

In the end, it seems that specifying the parameters (a,b,c,d,e) after using Solve gives me the parametrisation I am looking after, i.e. the one continuous in lambda, and thus I would like to see this parametrisation written down explicitly

Comment: Written down explicitly in terms of (a,b,c,d,e,lambda) and not numerical values and lambda

Comment: You basically think `Solve` should use the same general formula for the roots of $Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E = 0$, no matter whether the coefficients are symbolic expressions or numerical values? One can do that, though `Solve` does not seem to do it on its own. You're not guaranteed to get continuous formulas, though. (E.g. `ReImPlot[#, {d, -5, 5}] & /@ (SolveValues[e x^4 + d x^3 + c x^2 + b x + a == 0, x] /. {a -> -1, b -> -1, c -> 2, d -> d, e -> 1})`.) I know `Solve` tries to factor, and it may do other transformations depending on the coefficients. I don't know enough to explain it.